# Suppressing python warnings system-wide or cron-wide

Tags: python, cron

I have a lot of python scripts which generate

```
/home/intranet/public_html/intranet/bin/utils.py:172: DeprecationWarning: os.popen4 is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
  fin, fout = os.popen4(cmd)
```

and other warnings.

Is there a way to hide them system- or cron-wide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are all other warnings `DeprecationWarning`s? Run the script like this:

```
python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning thescript.py
```

If you want to ignore all warnings, use

```
python -W ignore thescript.py
```

To ignore warnings system- or cron-wide, set the env variable `PYTHONWARNINGS`:

```
PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore::DeprecationWarning
# or PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore
```

Documentation: [The -W option](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) and [PYTHONWARNINGS](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS).

What python version do you use? DeprecationWarning should be ignored by default in 2.7.

Comment: I have 2.6 version. Unfortunately PYTHONWARNINGS does not work in this version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want not to have output when you run programs trough cron you just need to add `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of your execution line.
This will redirect your regular output to null, but also the errors.